# Are BSON arrays heterogeneous or homogeneous?

Tags: bson

This is not explicitly stated in [the spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), although the example in the footnotes is given for a homogeneous array.

A google search doesn't yield a definitive answer.

Looking at various APIs, the contents are returned as an object rather than a homogeneous value/type, which can then be inspected dynamically.

The only practical reason I personally *can* see for a heterogeneous array is that if they contain `document`s, these may have different sets of fields. Otherwise a user would prefer a (heterogeneous) `document` over a (homogeneous) `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it ***does*** say so in the spec.

it says a *document* is made up of elements prepended with null bytes

```
document    ::=     int32 e_list "\x00"
```

a document is made up of elements

```
e_list  ::=     element e_list
```

and elements can be of any type BSON supports

```
element     ::=     "\x01" e_name double    64-bit binary floating point
    |   "\x02" e_name string    UTF-8 string
    |   "\x03" e_name document  Embedded document
 ....<snip>....
```

the first note at the bottom of the page explains that lists are simply documents with magic ascending string keys.

> Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with
>   integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing
>   sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded
>   as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}.

as such,
BSON will happily serialize `{"Key1":[12, "12", 12.1, "a string", Binary(0x001232)]}`

Comment: You missed `  |  "\x04" e_name document  Array`, for completeness.

Comment: I also just noticed there is a heterogeneous array example in the [FAQ](http://bsonspec.org/faq.html).